# user pref - implement default zoom scale for webview in fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment, zooming, scale

I've got a webview in a fragment. I have not found any of the recommended methods for setting initial zoom to be appropriated. Most people want to scale so the content fits within the webview. For ME, as one user, **that's exactly what I don't want**. I prefer to have the content zoomed larger than the view -- this allows me to read headings at larger size, and, I can scroll sideways if I need to read something longer.

So, with various users and devices, it's kind of pointless use a fixed zoom scale, or to try to guess what the user would want.

I have the zoom controls enabled, so, the user can set a desired zoom for a particular page... but, that only lasts until the user clicks a link (because newly loaded content uses the zoom scale that the webview was set to initially), or the user rotates the device (because destroy/create also takes us back to the webview's initial zoom scale).

The initial zoom scale can easily be set. Personally, I like 220:

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(220);
```

But, all new content is set to this scale, and, there's apparently no way to set the scale again, on-the-fly.

I can also set the scale with a user pref:

```
mWebView.setInitialScale(defaultPrefs.getInt("xyzBrowserScale", 220));
```

Hey, I can also detect and save whatever the user might set, himself, either in an onTouch callback, or in onPause:

```
public void onPause() {
    // save current zoom as preference setting
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = defaultPrefs.edit();
    ed.putInt("xyzBrowserScale", Math.round(mWebView.getScale()*100));
    ed.commit();
    super.onPause();
}
```

**Here's where it gets interesting and annoying**. No matter what callback I've used, that new setting is only going to be in effect when the webview is created next time -- because it relies on setInitialScale(). So, to make the selected zoom effective for new content, the user can rotate the device, to have the fragment and webview recreated!

That's what I'd call UI-silly: set your zoom, and rotate to make it useful.

So, the question is, how can this be executed more gracefully? I'm not aware of any method to force recreation of the fragment.

Or, have I missed something? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have a passable solution -- not THE solution -- in absence of something better. First, I had not been aware of WebViewClient's onScaleChanged() callback. That's a great place to get whatever the user adjusts the zoom to, and store it in a class variable:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    // stop links from opening in system browser
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
    public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
        currentZoom = Math.round(newScale*100);
    }
});
```

Then, I added an item to the overflow menu, to Save Zoom. On that menu click, I can save currentZoom to user prefs, and pop up a dialog with a note to rotate the device:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setMessage("Click OK, then rotate device to apply saved zoom")
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            }})
        .show();
```